# Python 3 - Implement a function to compute hourly wage and number of hours worked

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a question where I need to create a program that takes two arguments: an hourly wage and the number of hours an employee worked. Any hours beyond 40 is overtime and should be paid at a rate of **1.5** times more.

So far, I've come up with the following:

```
def wage(hourly, hours)
if hours > 40
#hours over 40 earns overtime rate
```

It should come out something along the lines of:

```
   >>> wage(10, 10) 
   100

   >>> wage(10, 35) 
   50

   >> wage(10,45)
   475
```

The function should output and calculate the values based off how the program is written. I'm just not sure how to implement the proper iteration with the user-defined function in order to output the proper values.

**As reference, heres the original question:**

Implement function 
wage() 
that takes two arguments: an hourly 
wage and the number of hours an employee worked in the last 
week. Your function should compute and return the employee’s 
pay. Any hours worked beyond 40 is overtime and should be paid 
at 1.5 times the regular hourly wage. Make sure to add a 
Docstring to tell the user how the program works.

Comment: Do you have more code to show?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to fix your indentation and other syntax errors?

Comment: Unfortunately this is where I'm stuck at. I know I have to make some sort of loop in order to factor in the overtime to incorporate that with the user defined function. I included the original question at the end if it helps at all.

Comment: Do you have any code you wrote yourself, or just the stubs your teacher gave you? As it is, I don't see any research effort here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a homework completion service.

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply hourly against hours, compute overtime and add that to salary.  Since you already added regular hourly rate, you add 0.5 * overtime.

```
def wage(hourly, hours):
    salary = hourly * hours
    if hours > 40:
        overtime = 40 - hours
        salary += 0.5 * overtime
    return salary
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if I strongly believe that you should really do it yourself, since you should know this thing if you are going to use Python, here is the answer:

```
def wage(hourly,hours):
        if hours > 40:
                payment = 40 * hourly  # Standard Payment until 40 Hours
                payment = payment + hourly * (hours-40) * 1.5  # + the rest which has more rate
                return payment
        else:
                return hours * hourly  # Otherwise Normal Payment
```

You need to find the amount of hours that the person worked that are over 40. These have the 1.5 rate. So, the first 40 hours have standard rate. That's why you need to subtract the first 40 hours from the rest, in the first case.